# How to dynamically assign an order value to a Google Ads conversion tracking script

Tags: whmcs, google-ads-script

I have an e-commerce store powered by WHMCS, and I have a Google Ads campaign I'd like to set up conversion tracking for.

Google Ads has given me the following code to track conversions on my WHMCS site.

```
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-xxx/xxx',
      'value': 10.0,
      'currency': 'AUD',
      'transaction_id': ''
  });
</script>
```

During the Google Ads conversion setup, they asked for a default conversion value which I set to AU$10.

I've added that conversion script to the `complete.tpl` file.

How do I dynamically set the value assigned to the Google Ads conversion based on the order that has just been made in on the order complete page?

I have the Google Analytics WHMCS app installed and configured.

I see there is no WHMCS Google Ads app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the `Google Ads`, but I integrated `Google Analytics 4` before stumbling upon the WHMCS app. So you can follow the same for `Google Ads`

1. First off, create a custom hook file in `includes\hooks`
2. In the file, create a `hook` for defining Google Ads calling script in the `head` tag (For further details, please see [ClientAreaHeadOutput](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/output/#clientareaheadoutput)):

   ```
   add_hook('ClientAreaHeadOutput', 1, function ($vars) {
       return '<script>Google Ads Script Here</script>';
   });
   ```
3. Add another hook for the `noscript` code in start of the `body` tag, if there is any (For further details, please see [ClientAreaHeaderOutput](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/output/#clientareaheaderoutput)):

   ```
   add_hook('ClientAreaHeaderOutput', 1, function ($vars) {
       return "<noscript>No Script Code Here</noscript>";
   });
   ```
4. Add another hook that will mark `conversion` when the invoice is paid, I have customized it to what you require (For further details, please see [InvoicePaid](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/invoices-and-quotes/#invoicepaid)):

   ```
   add_hook('InvoicePaid', 1, function ($vars) {
       $invoiceID = $vars['invoiceid'];
       $order = Capsule::table('tblorders')->where('invoiceid', '=', $invoiceID)->first();

       if ($order !== null) { // order exists
           $transactionID = $order->id;

           $orders = localAPI('GetOrders', array('id' => $transactionID));
           $order = $orders['orders']['order'][0];

           $result = localAPI('GetClientsDetails', array('clientid' => $order['userid']));
           $client = $result['client'];

           $currencyCode = $client["currency_code"];

           $total = 0;
           foreach ($order['lineitems']['lineitem'] as $product) {
               // get actual product pricing
               $price = (float)preg_replace("/[^\\d.]+/", "", $product['amount']);
               if ($product['type'] == 'product') {
                   $tempItem = Capsule::table('tblhosting')->where('id', '=', $product['relid'])->first();
                   if ($tempItem != NULL) {
                       $actualProduct = getProduct($product['pid']); // fetch original product for actual pricing

                       $selectedCycle = strtolower($product['billingcycle']);
                       $price = (float)$actualProduct['pricing'][$currencyCode][$selectedCycle];
                   }
               }

               $total += $price;
           }

           return "
               <script>
                   gtag('event', 'conversion', {
                       'send_to': 'AW-xxx/xxx',
                       'value': " . (float)$total . ",
                       'currency': '" . $currencyCode . "',
                       'transaction_id': '" . $transactionID . "'
                   });
               </script>";
       }
   });
   ```

Also don't forget to include the `Capsule` on top of the file as:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
```